# Setting Oracle APEX radio group default values

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have 3 radio groups on my page that are populated dynamically by a query. In the first radio button the last option is `N/A`. When `N/A` is selected, the user can select any value from the other 2 radio groups, but if value is not `N/A`, I need to limit the user selection in the other two radio groups to their default values.

I tried refreshing the radio groups and thus resetting them to values selecting by dafault but then the user still can change the selections. I also tried refreshing radio groups to reset selection and then disabling but then that removes their selected values from session. What else can I try to limit user selection to default values if the first radio group value is not `N/A`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: 2nd and 3rd radio group queries might use union of two `SELECT` statements; one that runs when the 1st radio group value is `N/A`, and another that runs when it is not `N/A`.

```
select ename d, empno r
from emp
where deptno = 10
  and :P1_RG = 'N/A'
union all
select ename d, empno r
from emp
where deptno <> 10
  and :P1_RG <> 'N/A'
```

I don't know what those defaults values are, but - you do, so include them into such a query.